# getting a string between 2 strings

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing

i have the following string

```
sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=productsearch&cd=1&cad=rja&docid=10829621560421678006&ved=0CDEQ9gIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww
```

i would like to parse this part out `10829621560421678006`

i am thinking about writing a function that returns the string between 2 specified strings which are in this case  `&docid=` and `&ved=`

any suggestions or a better solution?, note that i can't use split since the string structure will differ from time to time, my reference to this number are those 2 strings `&docid=` and `&ved=`

also is it possible to use regualr expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:-

```
 Dim startIndex As Integer = temp.IndexOf("&docid=") + 20
 Dim endIndex As Integer = temp.IndexOf("&ved=", startIndex)
 Dim extraction As String = temp.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Trim
```

and if you want to use Regex then you can simply try this:-

```
 docid=(.*?)&ved
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Strings.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split.aspx) for this:

```
Dim extracted As String = Split(Split(sourcestring, "&docid=")(1), "&ved=")(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is the best for my case ;-D

Answer (score 1):

Very simple and effective is this regex.

```
docid=(.*?)&ved
```

Result:

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => docid=10829621560421678006&ved
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10829621560421678006
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ like this:

```
var docid = 
    text
        .Split('&')
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .Where(x => x[0] == "docid")
        .Select(x => x[1])
        .First();
```